# Extract data from a CSV file based on the date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, physics

I am investigating the variability of Aerosol Optical Depth (AOD) with Temperature.

I have a list of dates in a csv file and I need to extract the temperature, at that given date, from a csv file containing the temp followed by the date.

This is the code I tried to use...
I need the Temperature for each date within the Plot_Dates file, in a separate list to be compared against another variable, also at that date.
For now I am just working on the first list, as the code can simply be copied, and I cannot extract the temperature data for when the dates match.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime

DATES = pd.read_csv("Plot_Dates.csv")
TEMP = pd.read_csv("Temp_Data.csv")
AOD = pd.read_csv("AOD_Data.csv")

AOD['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(AOD['Date'])
TEMP['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(TEMP['Date'])

DATES['TEMP_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(DATES['TEMP_Date'])
DATES['AOD_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(DATES['AOD_Date'])

Plot_Temp = []

for Date in DATES['TEMP_Date']:
    for TempDate in TEMP['Date']:
        if TempDate == Date:
                Temp = TEMP.loc[Date, 'Temperature']
                print(Temp)
                Plot_Temp.append(Temp)


print(len(Plot_Temp)) 
# This line is just a check to see if it works. Currently printing zero
```

The first few lines of the Temperature file are:

| Temperature | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 272.3417167622245 | 2021-01-01 00:00 |
| 272.1774031773405 | 2021-01-01 01:00 |
| 271.71183130162035 | 2021-01-01 02:00 |

I expect the list of temperatures to look like

"272.3417167622245, 272.1774031773405, 271.71183130162035".

I am doing the same process from some Aerosol Optical Depth (AOD) data and I will then plot these two variables against each other.

It is this line that does not work:

```
Temp = TEMP.loc[Date, 'Temperature']
```

Comment: Your question is missing [mre]s of your datasets. and a clear description of what you expect (providing the matching expected output).

Comment: Sounds like you should use a join here.

Comment: Try `df = pd.merge(DATES, TEMP, left_on='TEMP_Date', right_on='Date', how='left')`